# Eslint- VS Code. Creating and extending custom rules

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am using VS Code with eslint enabled. In most of my code i use string such as

```
var temp = "Stackoverflow";
var other=temp+" javascript";
```

I need a auto-fix option in es-lint such that it adds a (a static)comment at the end of line for the lines containing string on VS Code. like this

```
  var temp = "Stackoverflow"; //Custom comment
  var other=temp+" javascript"; //Custom comment
```

is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is that comment supposed to say? And what's the rule to identify those lines? "String assignment to variable" and "string concatenation with assignment to variable"?

Comment: @deceze The rules is wherever a string is used it needs a comment at the end of line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to submit your issues or a feature request regarding **Visual Studio Code** or it's **extensions** on the issues sections of their respective **GitHub** channel. If you want a desired feature in a VSCode, then go ahead and submit an issue with a **Feature Request** label/tag in the following GitHub issues page. (Or just the specific extensions' GitHub)

- [VSCode's ESlint Extension's GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues)
- [VSCode's GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues)

  [image: Screenshot]